# jQuery .load() How to prevent double loading from double clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, onclick

I am using jQuery load() function to load some pages into container. Here is the code:

```
$('div.next a').live('click',function() {

    $('.content').load('page/3/ #info','',function(){
        //do something
    });

return false;

});
```

Everything works just fine but the problem is when I quickly double click the div.next link, from console I see that it loads the page twice because I did a quick double click. I could even make it 3 clicks and it will load it 3 times and show in console smth like that:

```
GET http://site/page/3/     200     OK  270ms   
GET http://site/page/3/     200     OK  260ms
```

My question is how to prevent such double clicking and not to let load the target page more then once no matter how many times it was clicked.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the link to be clickable again once the page loads?

Comment: vice versa, I want to be disabled after its clicked and then be activated when the page is loaded into container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever happened to good ol' JavaScript? Why are you all trying to figure it out with pure jQuery?

```
var hasBeenClicked = false;

$('div.next a').live('click',function() {

    if(!hasBeenClicked){
        hasBeenClicked = true;
        $('.content').load('page/3/ #info','',function(){
            //do something
            //If you want it clickable AFTER it loads just uncomment the next line
            //hasBeenClicked = false;
        });
    }

    return false;
});
```

As a side note, *never never never* use `.live()`. Use .delegate instead like:

```
var hasBeenClicked = false;

$('div.next').delegate('a','click',function() {

    if(!hasBeenClicked){
        hasBeenClicked = true;
        $('.content').load('page/3/ #info','',function(){
            //do something
            //If you want it clickable AFTER it loads just uncomment the next line
            //hasBeenClicked = false;
        });
    }

    return false;
});
```

Why? Paul Irish explains: http://paulirish.com/2010/on-jquery-live/

To answer your comment...

This could happen if you have your delegate function nested inside your AJAX call (`.load()`, `.get()`, etc). The `div.next` has to be on the page for this to work. If `div.next` isn't on the page, and this isn't nested, just do this:

```
$('#wrapper').delegate('div.next a','click',function() {
```

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Delegate needs the selector to be the parent of the dynamically added element. Then, the first parameter of delegate (`div.next a` in the last example) is the element to look for within the selected element (`#wrapper`). The wrapper could also be `body` if it's not wrapped in any element.

Comment: Your version works like a charm but only with .live(). The .delegate does not recognize links from loaded page in my case. Any idea why would that happen?

Comment: Updated my answer, look at the bottom

Comment: If that still doesnt help with delegate can I see the rest of your code?

Comment: Your last update perfectly solved the problem. Thank you for your kind and detailed response!

Answer (score 1):

You could unbind the `click` event with `die()`:

```
$(this).die('click').click(function() { return False; });
```

Or you could give the element a `.clicked` class once it is clicked:

```
$(this).addClass('clicked');
```

And check if that class exists when performing your logic:

```
$('div.next a').live('click',function() {
    if (!$(this).is('.clicked')) {
        $(this).addClass('clicked');

        $('.content').load('page/3/ #info','',function(){
            //do something
        });
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: If I use a:not(.clicked) it works if I click once but if I perform double click it will just jump to page/3/ and wont load the page in container acting like a normal url. Any idea why?

Comment: Whoops, forgot about the `return false`. Check the updated code.

Comment: That keeps passing to page if quickly clicked twice... One click works fine. Weird.

Comment: Not sure I agree by injecting lots of classes onto a page to save state like this. Browser plugins can change classes for example, so can jQuery plugins. Classes aren't private and therefore aren't safe from outside interaction.

Comment: @Oscar Goodson: I agree and disagree with you. Classes are fine for storing state of a button, specially if it means display it differently (but not necessarily), plugins should not ever remove a class that is not theirs. Maybe adding a prefix to your classes will help avoid conflicts. However, in this case, since it's not affecting the look, I would chose to just have a variable that is set when click happens and unset when the load finishes since there's no need to access the DOM (which makes it unnoticeably faster :)

Comment: Yes, of course, if it's a "style" issue you should indeed use classes (this is why i said "save a state _like_ this"). But as you said, no need to slow down the DOM to do a check if something is or isn't loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the jquery one method:

```
$("a.button").one("click", function() {
       $('.content').load('page/3/ #info','',function(){
               //do something
       });
});
```

Comment: I did try this method before but it still repeats the loading on double and triple clicking

Comment: +1: I didn't know about this function! But how do you prevent the `a` element from jumping to the top of the page when clicked again?

Comment: Hmm.. per the jquery docs, it shouldn't do that (repeat the function logic on subsequent clicks).   Good point w/ the page jumping back up.  Let me give that some thought.

Answer (score 1):

Store whether you're waiting for the load in a variable.

```
(function() {
  var waitingToLoad = false;
  $('div.next a').live('click',function() {

    if (!waitingToLoad) {
      waitingToLoad = true;
      $('.content').load('page/3/ #info','',function(){
          waitingToLoad = false;
          //do something
      });
    }
    return false;
  });

})()
```